# Check if following items exist in the List<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings and I need to check if specific items(not one item) exist in that list.

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>() {"one","two","three","four","five" };
```

I need to find out if "one" and "three" is in that list. Is it possible with one linq query?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
var valuesToCheck = new[] {"one", "three"};
bool isAllInList = valuesToCheck.All(s => strings.Contains(s));
```

Comment: @Dilshod Without Linq, but also easy:

    `var valuesToCheck = new HashSet<string> { "one", "three", };
    bool areAllInList = valuesToCheck.IsSubsetOf(strings);`

Answer (score 3):

```
var findMe = new List<string>() { "one", "three"};
List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };

var result = findMe.All(f => strings.Any(s => f == s));
```